# Stop window scroll, scroll through list, resume windowscroll at end of list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery and I'm trying to implement a scroll section on my page where you loop over a list. Depending on which element in the list has the class active, a different div on the right of the list gets display: inline-block and the previous active element gets display:none.

Html:

```
<div class="o-technologies">
    <div class="o-technologies__list">
        <div class="o-technologies__list--label">
            <h2 class="">List</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="o-technologies__list--list">
            <ul>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="o-technologies__content">
        <div class="m-technology">
            <div class="m-technology__wrapper">
                <h2 class="m-technology__title">Technology 1</h2>
                <div class="m-technology__description">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-technology">
            <div class="m-technology__wrapper">
                <h2 class="m-technology__title">Technology 2</h2>
                <div class="m-technology__description">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-technology">
            <div class="m-technology__wrapper">
                <h2 class="m-technology__title">Technology 3</h2>
                <div class="m-technology__description">
                    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-technology">
            <div class="m-technology__wrapper">
                <h2 class="m-technology__title">Technology 4</h2>
                <div class="m-technology__description">
                    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $technologiesList = $(".o-technologies__list ul");

    $('.m-technology').each(function(i, el) {
        $technology = $(this).find('h2').text();
        if ( i === 0) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }

        $id = 'm-technology--' + $technology.toLowerCase();
        $(this).attr('id', $id);

        if ( i === 0) {
            $technologyItem = "<li class='active'><a href='#" + $id + "'>" + $technology + "</a></li>";
        } else {
            $technologyItem = "<li><a href='#" + $id + "'>" + $technology + "</a></li>";
        }

        $technologiesList.append($technologyItem);
    });
});
```

This works so far, so the titles are gathered and put in a list. The first list item gets the class active which gives it a different color. The first technology gets the active class as well which gives it display: inline-block. The rest of the items has display:hidden so they don't show.

Now I'm trying to make the next list item and m-technology get the active class when I scroll while hovering over the o-technologies div.

I can stop the window scroll by using the mouseover event and set the body overflow to hidden but I can't seem to get the scroll event working because the o-technologies div has no overflow.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/geordi-feijens/pen/RwPBxmK

Comment: please provide the css also or codepen so that we can understand what effect have you achieved till now.

Comment: @BharatDBhadresha Added a codepen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to listen to the wheel event on your ul element and then manipulate the elments(add and remove class)

below is the updated somewhat working code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $technologiesList = $(".o-technologies__list ul");

    $('.m-technology').each(function(i, el) {
        $technology = $(this).find('h2').text();
        if ( i === 0) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }

        $id = 'm-technology--' + $technology.toLowerCase().replace(" ","");
        $(this).attr('id', $id);

        if ( i === 0) {
            $technologyItem = "<li id='li-"+$id+"' class='active'><a href='#" + $id + "'>" + $technology + "</a></li>";
        } else {
            $technologyItem = "<li id='li-"+$id+"' ><a href='#" + $id + "'>" + $technology + "</a></li>";
        }

        $technologiesList.append($technologyItem);
    });
  $(".o-technologies__list--list ul").on("wheel",function(event){
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
    $currentActive = $(".o-technologies__list--list ul li.active");
    $currentActive.prev().addClass('active')
    $currentActive.removeClass('active')
    $('#'+$currentActive[0].id.replace("li-","")).removeClass('active')
    // console.log($currentActive.next()[0])
    $('#'+$currentActive.prev()[0].id.replace("li-","")).addClass('active')
}
else {
    $currentActive = $(".o-technologies__list--list ul li.active");
    $currentActive.next().addClass('active')
    $currentActive.removeClass('active')
    $('#'+$currentActive[0].id.replace("li-","")).removeClass('active')
    // console.log($currentActive.next()[0])
    $('#'+$currentActive.next()[0].id.replace("li-","")).addClass('active')
}
    
  })
});
```

```css
.o-technologies {
  display: flex; 
  
 &__list {
  text-align: center;
   flex: 0 0 50%; 

  &--label {

   > * {
    display: inline-block;
   }
  }
  &--list {
   ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;

    li {
     &.active {
      a {
       font-weight: 900;
       color: blue;
      }
     }

     a {
      text-decoration: none;
            color: black; 
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
  
  .m-technology {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 display: none;

 &.active {
  display: inline-block;
 }

 &__wrapper {
  h2 {
   margin-top: 0;
  }
 }
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="o-technologies">
    <div class="o-technologies__list">
        <div class="o-technologies__list--label">
            <h2 class="">List</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="o-technologies__list--list">
            <ul>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="o-technologies__content">
        <div class="m-technology">
            <div class="m-technology__wrapper">
                <h2 class="m-technology__title">Technology 1</h2>
                <div class="m-technology__description">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-technology">
            <div class="m-technology__wrapper">
                <h2 class="m-technology__title">Technology 2</h2>
                <div class="m-technology__description">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-technology">
            <div class="m-technology__wrapper">
                <h2 class="m-technology__title">Technology 3</h2>
                <div class="m-technology__description">
                    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-technology">
            <div class="m-technology__wrapper">
                <h2 class="m-technology__title">Technology 4</h2>
                <div class="m-technology__description">
                    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```